# How to make decimal digits of chisq.test four numbers ?

Tags: r

```
> options(digits=5)
> x<-c(139,138,112,111)
> y<-c(0.3,0.25,0.2,0.25)
> chisq.test(x,p=y)

Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x 
X-squared = 5.1667, df = 3, p-value = 0.16
```

The command `options(digits=4)`  can not make the digits output of chisq.test four numbers,how can i get p-value = 0.15997?

Comment: See also `options("scipen")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the p-value directly and round it however you need:

```
> chi_sq <- chisq.test(x,p=y)
> chi_sq$p.value
[1] 0.159992
> round(chi_sq$p.value, 5)
[1] 0.15999
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 x <- c(139,138,112,111)
 y <- c(0.3,0.25,0.2,0.25)
 a <- chisq.test(x,p=y)
 print(a,digits=5)
```

or just

```
print(chisq.test(x,p=y),digits=5)
```

... gives:

```
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x 
X-squared = 5.1667, df = 3, p-value = 0.15999
```

---

If you look at the object `chisq.test` creates:

```
str(a)
```

you'll see that it's of class `htest`.

So the question is "How does the print method work for htest?"

If you look at `?print`, the generic function, you'll see some classes have the `digits=` argument, which is really all you need, so you could guess to do what I originally suggested (as I did), but then since we see it's of class `htest`, we can find out about it via `getAnywhere`:

```
getAnywhere(print.htest)
```

and seeing it's in `stats` (as would have been the obvious first guess anyway), we could also have seen the code by:

```
stats:::print.htest
```

So either of those last two show you exactly what it does, and also how to modify its behavior using `print`, because you can see it definitely has the 'digits' argument. You could even write your own function if you really had a mind to.

Comment: I will give you a reluctant upvote because I do not think it is good to encourage new users to use partial argument matching.

Comment: @DWin Fair enough. I have amended it.