# Decimal places in Summary(model) output in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get more than 2 decimal places from model summary output when I use `nnet` package. I read other threads regarding this and none of those solutions seem to work for me. I tried:

```
options(digits=10)
summary(model)

 b->h1 i1->h1 i2->h1 i3->h1 i4->h1 i5->h1 
  0.94  -2.67   0.83  -1.06  -2.51  -0.69 
 b->o1 h1->o1 
  1.14  -3.41 
 b->o2 h1->o2 
 -0.62   3.92
```

I also tried:

```
summary(model,digits=10)

 b->h1 i1->h1 i2->h1 i3->h1 i4->h1 i5->h1 
  0.94  -2.67   0.83  -1.06  -2.51  -0.69 
 b->o1 h1->o1 
  1.14  -3.41 
 b->o2 h1->o2 
 -0.62   3.92
```

None of those solutions work for me. I have to use `caputure.output` after summary output If i output the entire model or use `coefnames` I can get more than 2 decimal places but that is not going to help me if I use `caputre.output`.

Comment: please give the code how you generated the model with and tell us, in what values from the model (fitted, residuals .....) you are interested.

Comment: options(digits=10) model = nnet(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data, size=2,decay=0.01, softmax=TRUE) summary(model) that is all i have in my code. I am interested in more decimal places when the weights are displayed when i use summary(model). thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
summary(model)$wts
```

This will give you the weights with maximum decimal points.

If you want to have other values, e.g. residuals or so, see the manual, I attach a screenshot of the relevant part:

[image: descrm]

Just write `summary(model)` then `$` and then e.g. `wts` to get the weights or e.g. residuals to get the residuals

Comment: This works. But now i have to capture.output both summary(model) and summary(model)$wts and then merge them for what i want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It's likely that the print method for the object returned by summary is where the two decimal places are coming from. As a first attempt, try

```
print(summary(model),digits=10)   ## or whatever other number of digits
```

If that doesn't work, try the kind of investigation that was done in this answer:

[How to make decimal digits of chisq.test four numbers ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606080/how-to-make-decimal-digits-of-chisq-test-four-numbers/15607327#15607327)